# PInvokeStackImbalance exception when using IntPtr in .NET 4? (Works in .NET 3.5)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, intptr

Might be a bit of noob question but it's something that's been getting me in a pickle for the past few hours (or days)...

I'm calling a method from a DLL in my code in .NET Framework 4.0

```
  [DllImport("xeneth.dll")]
    public static extern ErrorCode XC_GetFrame(Int32 h, FrameType type, ulong ulFlags, IntPtr buff, uint size);
```

and then using it here:

```
if (XC_GetFrame(myCam, XC_GetFrameType(myCam), 0, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)fs) != ErrorCode.E_NO_FRAME)
```

However, when I run this in .NET 4.0 I get a P/INVOKE error, however... running this in 3.5 does not trigger this error. After myself and another programmer have gone over the code we seem to have put it down to the IntPtr running differently on 4.0.

My application needs to run in .NET 4.0 as a couple of features required by the application are only available in 4.0 ...

Is there anything that maybe i'm overlooking or have simply forgotten to include?

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Tom

Update:

Native Declaration:

```
virtual ErrCode XCamera::GetFrame(FrameType type, unsigned long ulFlags, void *buffer, unsigned int size)
```

Error: A call to PInvoke function 'DLLTest!DLLTest.Form1::XC_GetFrameType' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: What is the native definition of the XC_GetFrame, and what exactly is the error you encounter?

Comment: Please explain what error you are getting?

Comment: Definition:
virtual ErrCode XCamera::GetFrame(FrameType type, unsigned long  ulFlags, void * buffer, unsigned int size) [pure virtual]

The rror is a PINVOKE Stack Imabalance: A call to PInvoke function 'DLLTest!DLLTest.Form1::XC_GetFrame' has unbalanced the stack.

Comment: Your code already had a bad import signature in .net 2, but that version was overly lenient with certain errors. .net 4 is stricter, exposing(and not causing) the bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two common causes for this:

1. Mismatch of calling conventions. Your C# code uses the default of `stdcall`. Perhaps the native code uses `cdecl`. Try adding `CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl` to the `DllImport` attribute.
2. Mismatch of parameter lists (see below).

Don't kid yourself that your code is alright because .net 3.5 doesn't raise this error. The error detection in .net 4 is better which is why you only see the errors there. But your code is broken in all .net versions.

---

The native definition for your C++ virtual method is:

```
virtual ErrCode XCamera::GetFrame(FrameType type, unsigned long ulFlags, 
    void * buffer, unsigned int size);
```

It looks like you are passing the object pointer as the first parameter in your pinvoke call. I think that could work, although I don't know enough about how virtual functions are handled when exported to know whether that's a problem. Presumably you have exported a plain C function to instantiate objects.

The other problem that I see is that on Windows, C/C++ `long` is 32 bits. A C# `long` is 64 bits. This means that the correct declaration for `ulFlags` is as `uint` in your C# code.

Comment: Added the calling convention to the DLLImport attribute, still getting the same error. Did I list the native function declaration correctly in the other answer?

Also, the application runs as normal if the framework is set to 3.5, but like you said the code could be broken.

Comment: Updated original post to include declaration :)

I presume by calling using PInvoke is also the same as:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; ?

Comment: When ever you call a function marked with the DllImport attribute, that's pinvoke.

Comment: Updated ulflags to type uint, other methods within this application that are called from the same DLL work though; which i'm pretty sure are C++ methods...

Comment: @Haden693 I think I was over-stating it. I suspect you can call C++ methods via pinvoke. You can't instantiate C++ objects, other than via a helper function that you have to export. I guess you already did this. And I really don't know how virtual methods work with pinvoke. Do you? Otherwise you need to fix the long mismatch and get the calling convention right.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head have you checked the bit-ness of both projects? You will get errors if one is 64-bit and the other is 32-bit. Note that in a recent version the default for C# projects changed from Any CPU to x86. That won't matter on a x86 OS, but on x64 OSes it makes a significant difference.

Additionally you should generally include as much of the text of the error as you can, censoring to protect private information is fine, but the error number and text can be quite helpful. Additionally when working with `extern` it is helpful to include both definitions of any `struct` types to ensure they are equivalent. (Another common problem).

Comment: Both projects are running under 32-bit, all DLL's associated are running under 32-bit too... The error i'm receiving when debugging is:

PInvokeStackImbalance: A call to PInvoke function 'DLLTest!DLLTest.Form1::XC_GetFrame' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: Definition of the function:

virtual ErrCode XCamera::GetFrame(FrameType type, unsigned long  ulFlags, void * buffer, unsigned int size) [pure virtual]

Comment: That can't possibly be it. You don't get as far as calling the function when there is a bit-ness mis-match.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Given the lack of error message, I wasn't certain when the other DLL would be loaded into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a better question is why it worked before. The declaration you provided:

`virtual ErrCode XCamera::GetFrame(FrameType type, unsigned long ulFlags, void * buffer, unsigned int size)`

has .NET types corresponding to: `FrameType, uint, IntPtr, uint`.

On Windows, `unsigned long` is a 32-bit type, while in C# `ulong` is a 64-bit type.